# I want to know the meaning of a sentence

Tags: expressions, sentence

So I read a novel and found a sentence "Jane waited on her boss's instructions". Does the sententence mean that Jane was waiting for her boss's instructions?

Comment: The expression 'wait on' is ambiguous; context only makes the 'wait, prepared to act upon' sense more probable rather than certain here. It _could_ merely mean 'waited for' (where I'd say the _multi-word verb_ status is dubious). It's rarely used in this context nowadays, being largely confined to restaurants etc and the set phrase 'waited on hand and foot'.

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly. To '*wait on*' is a phrase with a different meaning to 'wait *for*':

> 1.4: Remain in readiness for a purpose.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/wait)

When combined with a person, particularly a superior one, 'waiting on someone' means doing things for them, like a servant (or secretary, in your example).

Consider a waiter at a restaurant - a waiter *waits at* the tables, and *waits on* the customers:

> - ‘The only member of that group who will **wait on** tables next Sunday is Sean Carroll who has served at all of the 45 parties.’
> - ‘I felt like a fraud, sitting in a pleasant room, served three delicious meals a day and being **waited on** by quietly efficient and obviously busy staff who even spoke a little English.’
> - ‘He then worked as an electronic appliance technician before switching to blue-collar jobs such as **waiting on** restaurant tables and selling audio equipment.’

Examples from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/wait)

Comment: Lexico's sense 1:1?

Comment: @marcellothearcane But the secretary is not "waiting on her boss", she's "waiting on instructions" (from her boss).

Comment: @Edwin I'm confused. What?

Comment: To 'wait on' is * a string with **the same** meaning as 'wait for': [[Lexico, under 'wait'](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/wait)] (your link): **wait**... 1.1 _wait for_  or _on_ : Stay where one is or delay action until (someone) arrives or is ready. / 
‘he sits on the corner waiting for Mary’ / 
‘she was waiting on her boyfriend’. (but not my downvote; I usually consider one enough for a well-intentioned, researched, but somewhat one-sided answer). *also